# Elastix - Prioritize incoming DDI

Tags: asterisk, voip, elastix

i need a little help regarding the queues.
I have a situation where i want to set an incoming number as VIP number
so whenever that number calls in, it jumps to first place.
For example, we have 20 calls in queue, VIP number calls in, he would
automatically need to be first in queue.

Any ideas ?
I know that there's a blacklist function in Elastix, but i couldn't find any 
VIP list functions in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use queue priority module in elastix web.

If you have no such menu entry, you have use Module Admin and install it.

Comment: Great...Thank you. It was in front of my nose the whole time :-). Thanks again :-)